# how to install package in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04

When i have to install something then this appears:

```
dpkg: error processing package libgtk2-gladexml-perl (--purge):

 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
Errors were encountered while processing:

libgtk2-gladexml-perl 

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
.
```

Comment: Why did you remove `sources.list`? Sounds counterproductive.

Comment: How are you trying to install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall the package from the .deb-file directly:

```
sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/libgtk2-gladexml-perl_version.deb
```

Use *tab completion*, because the .deb-file is additionally named with a version number!

---

Now, update your system:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```